# Is there a generic way to say "not interacted with yet" in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input which content I would like to check prior to submission. Depending on the status (correct or incorrect input), I set a class to feedback to the user:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    input: ""
  },
  methods: {
    getClass() {
      if (this.input == "") {
        return "ko";
      } else {
        return "ok";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.ok {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: green;
}

.ko {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: red;
}

.initial {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-bind:class="getClass(input)" v-model="input">
</div>
```

It works fine, except that I would like to have a neutral styling prior to any manipulation of that given field (`<input>` in the example above) and to have the class `initial` applied in that case.

Is this something which is simple to do in Vue? I can imagine to listen to each `clicked` event and set the class based on that (first `initial` and then the right one depending on the content) but this is rather cumbersome.
In other words, there would be no indication to the user until his first interaction with that element.

Is there a natural way to achieve that?

Comment: There are libraries which do this sort of thing already, have a look at [VeeValidate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just add an extra property `touched` in data properties which is a Boolean value that holds whether an input is initially touched or not

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    input: "",
    touched: false
  },
  methods: {
    getClass() {
        if(!this.touched){
            return 'initial';
        }else{
            if(this.input == "") {
                return "ko";
            } else {
                return "ok";
            }
        }

    }
  }
});
```

set the value of `touched` to true on the input change

```
<input v-bind:class="getClass(input)" @change="this.touched = true" v-model="input">
```

Comment: I think OP's main problem is how to do this in a less cumbersome way, possibly across multiple form elements.

Comment: @DecadeMoon VeeValidate is also based on touched property

Comment: I should clarify -- your answer is correct (it was the first solution I thought of), I'm just saying that doing all this manually for a whole bunch of form elements would be very tedious. Yes I suggested to OP to check out VeeValidate for this very reason.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yep you are right and it has more functionality than mine thats the reason I upvoted voted your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to

1. Add `"isInteracted": false` to `data`
2. [Watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) `input` and set `isInteracted` to `true` on any change of `input`
3. Do not set class to anything unless `isInteracted` is `true`

This way your highlighting logic will not be triggered unless user has actually wrote something

Answer (score 0):

I think the `.once` modifier is there just for this purpose. So, I think this is the most declarative solution:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    input: "",
    isTouched: false
  },
  methods: {
    getClass() {
      return this.isTouched ? "ko" : "ok"
    }
  }
});

<div id="app">
  <input
    :class="getClass(input)"
    v-model="input"
    @input.once="isTouched = true"
  >
</div>
```